# Batch file to remove lines above and below certain phrase

Tags: batch-file

I rent a piece of software which saves docs in a textfile.

Each question is formatted into clusters, with a label in square brackets, followed by a list of values associated to that question, following on separate lines, as per excerpt below:

```
[Q1]
Answer = yes
Source = A
Value = 20

[Q2]
Answer = yes
Source = B
Value = 20

[Q3]
Answer = yes
Source = A
Value = 20
```

What I would like to do is strip out any complete blocks of text where Source = B, so that the outputted text file of the example above would read as:

```
[Q1]
Answer = yes
Source = A
Value = 20

[Q3]
Answer = yes
Source = A
Value = 20
```

Basically omitting

```
[Q2]
Answer = yes
Source = B
Value = 20
```

Can this be done? if so, what is the best method

Comment: Yes, you can use any language that has basic text processing and looping constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Batch file below was written *precisely* to solve this problem as it is stated, so it will *not* solve any other similar problem.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Source = B"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   if "!line:~0,1!" equ "[" (
      if "!Source !" neq " B" (
         echo !label!
         for %%v in (Answer Source Value) do echo %%v =!%%v !
         echo/
      )
      set "label=%%a"
   ) else (
      set "%%a"
   )
)
if "!Source !" neq " B" (
   echo !label!
   for %%v in (Answer Source Value) do echo %%v =!%%v !
   echo/
)
```

Comment: The example was a little more dumbed down than the actual scenario.

If I have some other groups in the file which have different labels, which I wish remain untouched/ignored, (i.e only analyze those where the label is [Qx] and not [CustDet] , [Dimension], etc.. how would I do that?

The final output should be a textfile which is identical to the input file, except any blocks omitted where the label is [Qx] and the Source = B